# Database operation fail. Record not updated

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, odbc

I have a page where admin could approve status of a list product by clicking the update button.

But I got this error recently which i do not know what causes it, could it be SQL database setting ?

Error message:

> Database operation failed.Record not update.[Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]po id:Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC
>   Drivers

Comment: Welcome to SO !,Information Provided in the question is insignificant to answer.Try explaining your Question,add some code snippet etc

Comment: Check your SQL drivers to make sure they are correct?

Comment: it is working previously, after database server migration, the error occurs. i already checked the connection string, it is correct and other functionality seems working well